# Bash = Shortcut to making a copy of a file in a remote directory?

Tags: bash

Is there a one-line bash shortcut for making a copy of a file in another directory, into that same directory?

For example, creating new Apache vhost using an existing vhost file as a template, without leaving the directory you are in:

```
sudo cp -p /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.example.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
sudo cp -p /etc/apache2/sites-available/{www.example.com,test.example.com}
```